# android data from previous intent not being save

Tags: android

I'm sure this is a novice question, but in my MainActivity I have a map of objects that I got from a sqlite database. This is just a simple listView that has an onClick that opens a detail view. The list works fine, and going to the details page works fine, but when I hit the back button to get back to the list my map is not in the same position as it was before. The keys are still intact so my listview LOOKS like it should, but the data behind the keys is either corrupted or missing compared to how it was before the view change. Is there something I have to do to preserve my map before switching to the detailView?

I could get the data again from the database but that seems really inefficient and poor practice.

Comment: You should look at implementing the onPause and onResume methods of your activity.

Comment: Do you have any stuff in your onResume/onPause? Are you using a adapter?

Comment: Your "workflow" should be something like => 1. Load SQL data, 2. Build list with listadapter Then if someone presses a listitem and presses teh backbutton, the list should be the same, don't reinitialize the data again.

Comment: So how would i preserve my data through an onPause / onResume method?